# How to store data out of the loop in MATLAB- Image Compression

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-compression

It is basic but I don't know how to do it.. I want to take 8x8 window in an image and further subdivide that window into 2x2 and then have to find their mean values. After doing this, I have to compare this mean value matrix with a threshold mean(mean value of whole image or mean value of that 8x8 window). If the elements greater than or equal to the threshold value, it should to be assigned 1 if not 0(converting it to a binary image). After all the operations a 256x256 image would become 128x128. Compression will be achieved. I have written this below code for this purpose.

After doing the all the operations, I don't know how to store the result (after comparing with the threshold value) after each loop. I need to do this to construct the compressed image. Please help. My codes take sometime to run. I think this can be coded more simply. Please explain me how to slide a window in an image and store how can I store the processed values to construct the output image.. so I can have a clear understanding ..Pls provide any materials to learn image processing basics like sliding a window and others things in MATLAB

My Code is here:

%In this code only the final window values are stored.. values of previous windows are not stored. I need to store the values of all the windows to get the compressed image. Help me.

```
I=imread('C:\Users\Prem\Documents\MATLAB\mandrill.jpg');
G=rgb2gray(I);
J=imresize(G,[256 256]);
thr=mean(J(:));
[m,n]=size(J); % Reading the size of the image
for i=1:m 
    for j=1:n

      P=J(i:(i+7),j:(j+7)); % Reading 8x8 window

        % Sub dividing the 8 x 8 window into four 4x4 sub windows 

    tl = P(1:4, 1:4); % top left sub-window
    tr = P(1:4, 5:8); % top right sub-window
    bl = P(5:8, 1:4); % bottom left sub-window
    br = P(5:8, 5:8); % bottom right sub-window

     % Sub dividing the 4 x 4 window into four 2x2 sub windows 

    newtl_1 = tl(1:2, 1:2); % top left sub-window
    newtr_1 = tl(1:2, 3:4); % top right sub-window
    newbl_1 = tl(3:4, 1:2); % bottom left sub-window
    newbr_1 = tl(3:4, 3:4); % bottom right sub-window

     % Sub dividing the 4 x 4 window into four 2x2 sub windows 

    newtl_2 = tr(1:2, 1:2); % top left sub-window
    newtr_2 = tr(1:2, 3:4); % top right sub-window
    newbl_2 = tr(3:4, 1:2); % bottom left sub-window
    newbr_2 = tr(3:4, 3:4); % bottom right sub-window

     % Sub dividing the 4 x 4 window into four 2x2 sub windows 

    newtl_3 = bl(1:2, 1:2); % top left sub-window
    newtr_3 = bl(1:2, 3:4); % top right sub-window
    newbl_3 = bl(3:4, 1:2); % bottom left sub-window
    newbr_3 = bl(3:4, 3:4); % bottom right sub-window

     % Sub dividing the 4 x 4 window into four 2x2 sub windows 

    newtl_4 = br(1:2, 1:2); % top left sub-window
    newtr_4 = br(1:2, 3:4); % top right sub-window
    newbl_4 = br(3:4, 1:2); % bottom left sub-window
    newbr_4 = br(3:4, 3:4); % bottom right sub-window

      % mean values of the four sub windows

        m1=mean(newtl_1(:));
        m2=mean(newtr_1(:));
        m3=mean(newbl_1(:));
        m4=mean(newbr_1(:));

         % mean values of the four sub windows

        m5=mean(newtl_2(:));
        m6=mean(newtr_2(:));
        m7=mean(newbl_2(:));
        m8=mean(newbr_2(:));

         % mean values of the four sub windows

        m9=mean(newtl_3(:));
        m10=mean(newtr_3(:));
        m11=mean(newbl_3(:));
        m12=mean(newbr_3(:));

        % mean values of the four sub windows

        m13=mean(newtl_4(:));
        m14=mean(newtr_4(:));
        m15=mean(newbl_4(:));
        m16=mean(newbr_4(:));

     M=[m1 m2 m3 m4; m5 m6 m7 m8; m9 m10 m11 m12; m13 m14 m15 m16];

OutputCompressedImage=M>thr;

    end
end
    imshow(OutputCompressedImage)
```

%In this code only the final window values are stored.. values of previous windows are not stored. I need to store the values of all the windows to get the compressed image. Help me.

Answer (score 0):

you are overwriting your OutputCompressedImage every loop iteration, that's why you only get the the final window value.
One way to do it is to use a three dimensional array to save your data, each slice representing one window.

your loop can be modified the following way:

```
s=1;
for i=1:m 
    for j=1:n
      ****keep original code****
      OutputCompressedImage(:,:,s)=M>thr;
      s=s+1;
    end
end
```

The dimension of OutputCompressedImage shoud have m*n slices.

P.S. for moving a window across you can consider using convolution. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html

Comment: I did as you have said.. I get following error.. Error using imageDisplayValidateParams>validateCData (line 117)
Unsupported dimension.

Error in imageDisplayValidateParams (line 31)
common_args.CData = validateCData(common_args.CData,image_type);

Error in imageDisplayParseInputs (line 79)
common_args = imageDisplayValidateParams(common_args);

Error in imshow (line 220)
  [common_args,specific_args] = ...

Error in meanthr (line 81)
    imshow(OutputCompressedImage);

Comment: yeah, that's saying you can not imshow a 3D matrix, cause images are 2 dimensional. if you do imshow(OutputCompressedImage(:,:,i)), it will show you the compressed image of the i th window. so it's upto you to figure out how to put all the windows back together and form a complete image.

Comment: you need to tile those together, maybe with a loop.

Comment: Please help me do that.. I am very new to matlab.. Hope you will save my day. I am trying reshape function but getting error..